# Convert spaced table text to array. Strip more then 2 spaces

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to convert the below string to a array
[image]

I tried things like:

```
$myArray = [];
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
    $l = 0;
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        //$myArray[$l] = array_map('trim', explode("                  ", $line));
        //$myArray[$l] = preg_split("/\s*[" . preg_quote(implode("", array(' ')), "/") . "]+\s*/", $line);
        $myArray[$l] = preg_split('/[    ,]/', $line, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);  // or '/ |,/'
        $l++;
    }

    dd($myArray);
```

But all are just to strip words with space between to a array. I want the system to regonize more then 2 spaces and use that as a split and trim the rest of the spaces.

I cant find another similar question about this here on stackoverflow

Comment: And, of course, input sample as image rather than text, so you make sure we can't copy paste for tests

Comment: I couldn't find a good way to paste the text without breaking the mark-up of it. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"/\s{2,}/"` to split using at least 2 whitespaces :

```
$str = "hello world   so much space around me, and even tabs         a b c  final part";
var_dump(preg_split("/\s{2,}/", $str));
```

Output :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "hello world"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "so much space around me, and even tabs"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "a b c"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "final part"
}
```